# GA-P55A-UD4 SYSFAN 2 problem

Tags: motherboard, fan

I have some strange problems with the mobo in title. I have two fans connected to SYSFAN 1 and 2. Both are the same temp regulated Arctic Cooling F12. They are regulated thru temp sensor which is in different cable from fan. It connects to the 3 pin.

So, I connected them to SYSFAN 1 and 2 MB ports. The problem is, when PC starts, the fan connected to SYSFAN 1 spins nice and is reporting speed to BIOS. But second fan connected to SYSFAN 2 starts to spin, than stops. I tried to warm the sensor with no help. Also, in BIOS I found no feature about SYSFAN 2 mode or something. I tried the fan itself by connecting it to PWR fan connector and it works fine. But obviously I want it to operate in SYSFAN 2. Please if you have any advice, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-p55a-ud4(p)_v2.0_e.pdf) , sysfan 2 has 4 pins, maybe you have the 3 pin connector in the wrong position?